# Firebase Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, firebase

I am working on a phonegap/cordova ionic app. I am testing on iOS and Android.

On iOS all works well.

However on Android, I get the following message when one of my views loads:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Each time I get this "warning" - my view does not load.

One of the .lp?dframe=t&id=...&pw=... queries that are to/from firebase has the following:

```
<html><body><script>
function EnvSendPing(destURL) {
try{
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", destURL, false);
xhr.send(null);
} catch (e) { }
}
function EnvDisconnect() {
EnvSendPing("/.lp?disconn=t&id=294802&pw=LL8E8eo2Rz");
}
if(window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener('unload',EnvDisconnect,false);
else if(window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent('onunload',EnvDisconnect);
</script></body></html>
```

which clearly has the xhr in as async "false" - causing this "warning".

Is there a way in which I can force ALL Firebase queries to have async true. 
If this is just a "warning" why should the page stall?

Note that on iOS and on Chrome and Safari on the desktop - all works as expected.

Comment: The warning is probably unrelated to the page not loading. [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: Thanks @Kato - will post more details - as I discover them. Agree, that It seems very XY-ish right now ;-)

Comment: I mean, on second thought, maybe the warning could be relevant. It's possible that it's having "detrimental affects on the end user experience" : )  But we're not seeing this in other apps or clients. Are you on the latest version of the SDK?

Comment: I have an almost empty ionic project, in chrome, and I get this error when I call     var ref = new Firebase("https://APP.firebaseio.com"); in a controller. I installed with bower install firebase. Firebase.SDK_VERSION = '2.2.7';

Comment: Same warning here... hence my SO question about running FB in a web sorker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520936/is-there-an-easy-way-to-run-firebase-in-a-web-worker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the issue was due to commenting out of cordova.js as suggested by ionic-service-deploy documentation.

Uncommenting that, ensures smooth WS connectivity to Firebase. Why it should be such is beyond me - but I have tested by repeatedly adding and removing the include in my index.html to have the effect consistently reproduced on Android/4.4.4 device.

Hope this is of help to others - I spent a large time finding this out!

Comment: Can you be more specific as to exactly what line/s of code you uncommented and/or commented out?

Comment: <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <!-- hide when using deploy/hidden as per deploy documentation -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>  // comment this out for deploy to work but then the XHTTP issues will show up on Android 4.4