# Is there an easy way to run Firebase in a web worker?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-worker

I have a single page React application which consists of many files, bundled with gulp/browserify.

Firebase javascript is embedded in this bundle.

**I'd like to know if there is an *easy* way to run certain Firebase operations on another worker thread ?**

---

What I have tried :

Setting up a worker and sending the Firebase object, or instance, *via* `worker.postMessage(xxx)`. In both cases, it throws an error which says `the object cannot be cloned`. Example bellow with the Firebase object.

```
var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([ '(',
    (function() {
        var onmessage = function(event) {
            var FB = new event.data.Firebase('my firebase URL');
            // Here, some Firebase operations
            // ...
        };
    }).toString(),
')()' ], { type: 'application/javascript' }));
var postViewedWorker = new Worker(blobURL);
URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);

[... later on ...]

postViewedWorker.postMessage({Firebase: Firebase, ...otherParams});
```

In the above example, the Worker works (haha) until I try to pass Firebase.

---

What I would like to avoid :

Setting two completely different bundles, one with the main application, and one dedicated to all Firebase operations, with a helper lib to send operations from one another.

---

*Note : The reason behind this question is because my UI is slowed by Firebase operations. For example, I have a list of items displayed on a page, and when I scroll, each time an item is visible, the `view` count of this object is updated with Firebase. The page scrolling is smooth without those operations, and becomes jerky when I add them.*

*Edit: Also, I consistently get the following warning : `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.`*

Answer (score 3):

Easy, depends on your values for easy.  Possible, definitely.

I used microdom to get it working.  Here's a rough/dirty version, bundle as makes sense to you.

In your worker:

```js
importScripts("http://raw.github.com/tmpvar/microdom/master/microdom.min.js");
var window = microdom('<html></html>');
var document = window;
importScripts("https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.2/firebase.js");

var ref = new Firebase(input.firebase_endpoint);
// This ref now works, authenticates, etc.  You can use .notify() to pass info to the main thread, etc.

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    output.notify(snapshot.val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a working open source implementation that puts Firebase into a worker: https://github.com/pkaminski/fireworker.  It can use both plain and shared workers (where supported) and integrates extra features from other Firebase add-on libraries.  It emulates the Firebase API and automatically bridges calls from the main page to the worker, so your existing code should more-or-less continue to work as-is.  It also has some non-trivial limitations, as of this writing:

- Only supports Firebase SDK 2.4.2. Could probably be adapted to SDK 3.x but it's going to be harder since the source code is not available.
- Interactive authentication methods don't work; calling `authWithPassword`, `authWithOAuthPopup`, or `authWithOAuthRedirect` will throw an exception. Instead, use your own server for login and call `authWithCustomToken`.
- Item priority is not currently implemented. Because priority is stored out of band it's difficult to support efficiently, and Firebase folks have indicated that it's essentially deprecated anyway.